# Enemy move is wrong why?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to create a spaceship game to using pygame. I want to enemies movement like this:
first enemies moving x coordination and enemy x coordinate increasing on x (moving right)
if enemy coordinates x >= WIDHT , enemy coordinates y += 5 and enemy x coordinate is decreasing on x (moving left)
if enemy coordinates x <= 0 ,enemy coordinates y -= 5 and enemy x coordinate is increasing on x (moving right)

I want to move enemies like this, but I typed code and enemies not moving as I want:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
WIDTH , HEIGHT = (750, 600)

WIN =  pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
BG_IMAGE = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("yeni_resim.jpg"),(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
CAPTION_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
ENEMY_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
BULLET_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
PLAYER_IMAGE = pygame.image.load("warship.png")
```

Creating Bullet Class

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = img
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self, vel):
        self.y += vel

    def off_screen(self, height):
        return not (self.y <= height and self.y >=0)

    def collision(self, obj):
        pass
```

And creating ship class(for warship and enemy)

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ship_img = None

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.ship_img, (self.x, self.y))

    def get_width(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_width()
    def get_height(self):
        return self.ship_img.get_height()

class Player(Ship):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.ship_img = PLAYER_IMAGE
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def draw(self, window):
        super().draw(window)
```

This is enemy class and i create def for enemy movement:

```
class Enemy(Ship):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.ship_img = ENEMY_IMAGE
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel):
        self.x += vel

        if self.x >= 684:
            self.x -= vel
            self.y += 5
        elif self.x <= 0:
            self.x += vel
            self.y += 5


def main():
    run = True
    FPS = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    player = Player(350, 500)
    player_vel = 8
    enemy = Enemy(350, 100)
    enemy_vel = 5


    def redraw_window():
        WIN.blit(BG_IMAGE,(0,0))
        player.draw(WIN)
        enemy.draw(WIN)
        pygame.display.update()

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        redraw_window()
        enemy.move(enemy_vel)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x + player_vel + player.get_width() < WIDTH:
            player.x += player_vel
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x - player_vel > 0:
            player.x -= player_vel



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False


main()
```

Comment: Walk through that `Enemy.move()` algorithm in your head.  So an Enemy x-position is 684, and velocity is subtracted, leaving x at say 679.  Next iteration, x is back to being < 684, so the velocity is added, moving x *back* to 684.  It's butting up against the side.  Also Y is increasing every step. maybe this is by design, but it will move the Enemy object diagonally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing your move function and replacing it with this in the while loop:

```
enemy.x += enemy_vel
if enemy.x >= WIDTH - ENEMY_IMAGE.get_width() or enemy.x <= 0:
    enemy_vel *= -1
    enemy_y += 5
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it would be better with some explanation as to what is currently wrong, and how this change solves that problem.

Comment: Thank you so so much friends it works. Now i am happy so much  :)))))

Comment: @Kingsley your right, I'll explain: first, the enemy velocity is 5, so the x coordinate is moving right 5 pixels. In the if statement it asks if the x coordinate is greater than the width or if it is less than 0. If that is true, then you multiply the velocity by -1, because that would make an opposite velocity. Finally, you add 5 to the y coordinate.

Comment: @Softwareprogrammer94 glad I could help :)